# How to stop while loop from accounting for negative number?

Tags: java, eclipse

For class I am writing a program that accepts a stream of positive integers. The program will stop accounting for numbers and compute the average once a negative number is entered into the console.

My issue is, I keep writing while loops that account for the negative entered. How do I stop this? I have tried the following

```
do{
     if (number < 0){
         break;
     } else if ( number >= 0) {
         number = input.nextDouble();
            DivideBy++;
            sum+=number;
     }
 }while (number >= 0);
```

When entering 1.1, 1.9, 3, and -1, the program prints 1.25, when the correct answer is 2.

Here is another example of what I have tried:

```
do { 
    number = input.nextDouble();
    DivideBy++; 
    sum+=number;
 }while (number >= 0);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: Read and check the number *before* adding it to the total?

Comment: Hint: (1.1+1.9+3+-1) / **4.** = 1.25

Comment: Remember, variable names in Java start with lowercase by convention, so it should be `divideBy` but since this denotes an action, i.e. method, `divisor` is even better.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double number = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    int divideBy = 0;
    double avg = 0;

    while(number >= 0) {
        System.out.println("Enter number: ");
        number = input.nextDouble();
        if(number < 0){
            break;
        }           
        sum+=number;
        divideBy++;
        avg = sum/divideBy;
    }

    System.out.println(avg);
```

Your if statement should come after the number has been read from the keyboard :]

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, it worked for me:

```
while(number >= 0){
  total = number + total;


} //Your average logic here//
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing now is checking whether the number is negative *after* you incremented `DivideBy` and added the number to the sum.

You can easily fix this by undoing what you did after a negative number.

```
// outside the loop:
sum -= number;
DivideBy--;
```

Then you will get the correct result.

Or, you can do it like this - check negative first, then add it to sum.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int num = s.nextInt();
int count = 0;
int sum = 0;
while (num > 0) {
    sum += num;
    count++;
    num = s.nextInt();
}
System.out.println(sum / count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the number before the if condition. Try this.

```
do {
      number = input.nextDouble();
      if (number < 0) {
        break;
      } else if (number >= 0) {
        DivideBy++;
        sum += number;
      }
    } while (number >= 0);
```